# Azure AD B2C JWT Token Signature Validation Failed

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-ad-b2c, claims-based-identity

I am trying to validate a valid JWT using this code below but am getting a strange error

```
 [Error]   IDX10516: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key: 
kid: '-KI3Q9nNR7bRofxmeZoXqbHZGew'. 
Number of keys in TokenValidationParameters: '1'. 
Number of keys in Configuration: '0'. 
Exceptions caught:
 '[PII of type 'System.Text.StringBuilder' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. 
token: '[PII of type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. Valid Lifetime: 'True'. Valid Issuer: 'False'
```

**Code:**

I had seen a lot of reference links on this issue but still not getting what am I missing?
I tried to test locally, its worked perfectly but after deployed to Azure Function its failing.

Configuration Settings:

```
"JwtSettings:TenantName": "OSHDev.onmicrosoft.com",

"JwtSettings:TenantId": "5492b240-96ee-44a1-bdcb-fa0ba0200111",

"JwtSettings:AadB2cInstance": "https://OSHDev.b2clogin.com/{0}/v2.0/",

"JwtSettings:OpeinConfigUrl":"https://OSHDev.b2clogin.com/OSHDev.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_SIGNUP_SIGNIN/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration",
```

```
       public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> ValidateAccessToken(string accessToken, JwtSettings jwtSettings, ILogger logger)
        {
            var audience = jwtSettings.Audience;
            var tenant = jwtSettings.TenantName;
            var tenantid = jwtSettings.TenantId;
            var aadb2cInstance = jwtSettings.AadB2cInstance;
            var openidconfigurl = jwtSettings.OpeinConfigUrl;

//Debugging purposes only, set this to false for production
                Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = false;

            ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configManager =
               new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(
                   openidconfigurl,
                   new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());

            OpenIdConnectConfiguration config;
            config = await configManager.GetConfigurationAsync();

            //Microsoft Identity to override claim names . If we remove below code line, "sub" claim will not be visible. Its visible under "nameidentifier"
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

            JwtSecurityTokenHandler? tokenValidator = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            // Initialize the token validation parameters
            TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {

                // App Id URI and AppId of this service application are both valid audiences.
                ValidateAudience = true,               
                ValidAudiences = new[] { audience },

                ValidateIssuer= true,
                ValidIssuers =  new List<string>()
                {
                   string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadb2cInstance, tenantid),
                   string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadb2cInstance, tenant)
                },

                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                // Support Azure AD V1 and V2 endpoints.
                IssuerSigningKeys = config.SigningKeys,
                RequireSignedTokens = true,
                //Debugging purposes only, set this to true for production
                ValidateLifetime = true
            };

            try
            {
                //Validate JwTToken and return Claims Prinicpals
                ClaimsPrincipal? claimsPrincipal = tokenValidator.ValidateToken(accessToken, validationParameters, out SecurityToken securityToken);
                return claimsPrincipal;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: can i see the .welknown url ? i can access from the internet ? i have tried:https://testb2c.b2clogin.com/testb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_SIGNUP_SIGNIN/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration but not working

Comment: @GAOUL Well known url which is accessible through internet. https://OSHDev.b2clogin.com/OSHDev.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_SIGNUP_SIGNIN/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

Comment: you have resolved your issue

Answer (score 0):

Like the error said, your token validator try to find the public key that is used to sign your token in the **jwks_uri**, you can find it in your **well-known** URL.

In each token there is a header "KID", this header indicate the ID of the public key used to sign your token.
When i check your **jwks_uri** there is no KID with ID :

```
"-KI3Q9nNR7bRofxmeZoXqbHZGew"
```

But:

```
"veMP2TrHLgs4XvKYJhumvhPW6O-WpbdSGqKdetRmvxI"
```